# How to turn on matching braces VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I just installed VS 2017 but I can't seem to get matching braces turned on. I tried changing colors in the tools editor but that didn't work. Not sure what I did to turn this off.

[image: Matching Braces]

[image]

Comment: So you set the brace matching background color in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors? I use 2015, but the path should be similar.

Comment: yeah i set it, changed different colors too and nothing, Even when I manually highlight one brace it doesn't match the closing brace

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of that settings page? Not sure how much it will help, but you never know..

Comment: ok i added it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for some reason its only for JavaScript files. If this happens to you, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service and uncheck the Enable the new JavaScript language service. If you have any JavaScript files open at the time you do this, you will need to close and then reopen them.