# Highlight Matching Brace In Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm unable to use the Pair matching feature for brackets in Visual studio 2017 community even though I tried changing the color through font and colors option as shown in the picture:

[image: Options]

Comment: In VS 2017 Pro there is an extra option of "Brace Matching" that changes the brace colours when you have one selected. The two options shown in your image didn't change any colouring for me

Comment: @AFriend What you described is also exactly what works in VS2015 Community for me.

Comment: That third option seems to also exist in VS2017 Community v15.6.7. What version are you using? Try updating to the latest version maybe?

Comment: Javascript? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45358280/6196568

Comment: i don't have the pro version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here :

[How to set the color of matching braces in VS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27756510/how-to-set-the-color-of-matching-braces-in-vs-2015)

They mentioned that this is a known issue and is on the list to get fixed but it's right now available in Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9. You can use `Visual Assist options`

The developer community  of VS answered: 
"Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed the problem in an upcoming release. We believe this was a perf issue (as that operation can frequently be canceled), which should be much quicker when the 15.8 version of VS2017 ships."

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/230322/brace-matching-in-javascript-not-working.html

See this:
https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W182

Answer (score 1):

I am using version 15.7.3 and I got an extra entry - just called brace matching. In my case it works properly

[image]

Comment: i don't have this option ;(